# In Salesforce Lightning Console- Can not add opportunity as sub tab for Case

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I can not add Opportunity as subtab for Case. I need Opportunity subtabs to open whenever I view a Case in the Salesforce Console APP

Answer (score 0):

*This is admin task with high chance of no coding needed so you might have more luck on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/.*

There's no direct connection between the two. Maybe you could pull it off (really subtabs) if you'd make the console work with Account as primary tab, you'd have to play with it.

Can clever usage of "related list - single" component be enough for your needs? Change first dropdown in editor to say "Account Name", not "use this case" When I click them in my sample console (Case is primary tab) they nicely open on subtab.

[image]

[image]

When all else fails - you could code something that uses Lightning Console API, [`openSubtab()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_openSubtab.htm) for example.